# VGA to ethernet

Tags: networking, ethernet, vga, headless, rj-45

SSH is a protocol used to communicate with headless systems but when there is pxe and bios problems it becomes too difficult to handle specially if we don't use serial console , kvm and other *currently available* (afaik) out of band management [procedures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_management). All headless systems almost always have a serial , vga and a ethernet outlet, in which serial and ethernet will need drivers which are initialized post boot through OS. Now my question :

Do we have some protocol for **vga to ethernet** or **crossover rj45** or something similar for *communication* in such cases since ethernet port is almost always available in desktop and laptops. Seeing its importance in critical systems and conditions, should we not have a driver and communication console package similar to *minicom* available as a library or (kernel?) module? If not why?

Comment: Intel vPro solves this complete problem as the vPro chip provides a complete VNC-style KVM-over-Ethernet relying only on the computer having power and and Ethernet connection.

Comment: well its still hardware ( intel ) specific and out of band . my question is why not build a flow from vga to commonplace ports.

Comment: Probably because of the lack of storage for drivers, libraries and the potential requirement for a kernel of some sort... I appreciate vPro is manufacturer specific but it is probably the best solution as it doesn't require any VGA, USB or other peripherals. I don't know the answer to your question, but I know vPro already negates the need for a solution.

Comment: I don’t understand. What you ask about (OS-independent remote administration) is the very definition of out-of-band management. It obviously exists. If it has to be independent, it cannot be in-band.

Comment: true. theoretically we can call it out of band. but current OOB techniques require additional hardware.

Comment: There are probably KVM Extenders that extend VGA over ethernet.  I've even had a KVM Extender that extends USB over Ethernet in between!

Comment: Of course it requires *dedicated* hardware. How else would you get the “flow from VGA to commonplace ports”? It’s not necessarily extra hardware, many enterprise devices/motherboards have OOB management built in.

Comment: ok. let us go back a bit. let's consider serial vs ethernet . [http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31171/internet-vs-serial-communication] - 802.3 is putting osi stack on rs-232 . hence we have connectors like serial to USB  which work without external dependency. on software part we have ser2net which maps to tcp port which can then be listened on 802.3 standards. Now if we analyze how VGA evolved from DB9 / rs-232 serial to DE 15 / vga  both having same E shell , there is a area which is not explored for converting vga to 802.3 standards using a connector and nothing more.

Comment: “802.3 is putting osi stack on rs-232” No it’s not...? VGA didn’t evolve from RS-232 in any way either. RS-232 is digital. VGA is analog. I think you’re quite confused about form factors and electrical/protocol compatibility.

Comment: ofcourse 802.3 is serial in physical layer - both are character devices. then tcp acquires osi layers. thats the reason raw data can be listened at tcp port in ser2net. also what i meant by vga evolution was based on the physical connector shell and not on protocol ( which i misplaced with db9 ) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-subminiature#Computer_video_output   , 
But well both 802.3 and rs-232 are digital and vga is analog - there you caught the point which i was missing. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean Cat5.. the cable. Rather than the ethernet protocol.

If you wanted ethernet the protocol then maybe you'd want some kind of ethernet over IP with KVM Extenders.  I haven't really tried that.. So, ethernet aside.

Yeah.. Any KVM Extender.

Or if you google for VGA over Cat5  then you'll see that specifically for VGA. e.g. I see a company called startech do one but ridiculously expensive.

https://www.startech.com/uk/AV/Extenders/VGA/VGA-to-Cat-5-Monitor-Extender-Kit-250ft-80m-VGA-Cat5-Extender~ST121UTPEP

[image]

So, Their one there looks ridiculously expensive.

However, with these kind of things you can often find things on ebay quite cheaply, even the best makes sometimes, or cheaper makes that do just as good, but try to check reviews first e.g. newegg might have reviews of this/that product.

My point though is they exist.. Look for keywords of USB, VGA, Cat5 extend.  and "vga extender" and "kvm extender"

Answer (score -1):

As @barlop noted there are video extenders that transmit video over cat5 or better. Most of these are not Ethernet based and must have all pares connected not just pars two and three. That said there in also what are called kvm over ip (which normally uses Ethernet). Unlike the extenders which are sold in pairs, these use a computer to display the video. Also note if you thought the extenders were expensive, you were wrong, these are expensive.

Comment: Commentary submitted as an isn't an acceptable answer

Comment: @Ramhound, What do you mean?